# Doxygen does not generate documentation for stand alone functions

Tags: c++, doxygen

The doxygen setup I am using works great for classes, structs, and namespaces, but does not generate any documentation for stand alone functions.

For instance, nothing is generated for these methods:

```
#ifndef STRING_UTILS_H
#define STRING_UTILS_H 1
/// @file

/// @brief Trim whitespace from the start of the string
/// @param s - The string to left trim
/// @return the trimmed string
std::string ltrim(const std::string& s);

/// @brief Trim whitespace from the end of the string
/// @param s - The string to right trim
/// @return the trimmed string
std::string rtrim(const std::string& s);

/// @brief Trim whitespace from both sides of the string
/// @param s - The string to trim
/// @return the trimmed string
std::string trim(const std::string& s);

#endif
```

Comment: Does Doxygen generate any errors? Any does it generate anything at all fir these files?

Comment: There are no errors, 1 un-related warning, and nothing from this file at all.

Comment: Have you tried fixing the `@file` command.  It needs a parameter.  Also, configure Doxygen to generate a warnings file.  Look and see if there are any other issues.

Comment: I'll try, but the documentation states it may be omitted: https://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/commands.html#cmdfile

Comment: Your Doxy comments appear to work with Doxygen 1.8.13 as expected using a default configuration. The above documentation appears in **Files -> File List** and **Files -> File Members**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SHOW_FILES` must be set to `YES` in the Doxygen file in addition to having `/// @file` in the source file